# Please explain me this code of Delimiter matching with stacks

Tags: java, algorithm, stack

```
/** Test if delimiters in the given expression are properly matched. */
public static boolean isMatched(String expression) {
  final String opening = "({[";          // opening delimiters
  final String closing = ")}]";          // respective closing delimiters
  Stack<Character> buffer = new LinkedStack<>();
  for (char c:expression.toCharArray()) {
    if (opening.indexOf(c) != -1)        // this is a left delimiter
      buffer.push(c);
    else if (closing.indexOf(c) != -1) { // this is a right delimiter
     if (buffer.isEmpty())               // nothing to match with
       return false;
     if (closing.indexOf(c) != opening.indexOf(buffer.pop()))
       return false;                     // mismatched delimiter
    }
  }
  return buffer.isEmpty();               // were all opening delimiters matched?
}
```

1. Assume a generic stack interface, `Stack<E>` with  unimplemented methods: `push( E )`, `pop()`, `isEmpty()` where `E` is a generic data type.
2. And a `LinkedArray<E>`  class implementing all `Stacks<E>` methods.
3. 'expression'  in 'isMatched()' is a mathematical expression with braces as delimiters. Ex- `[{(a+b)*(c+d)}]`; and
4. `isMatched(String expression)` is a method to check whether the expression contains correctly paired braces.
5. `buffer` is a stack to store the pushed expression's (now an array of `char`) members.

I am able to understand the code till the for-each loop. 
And the lines after that are eating me.

Comment: Don't insert link to *image* of code. Paste the code into the question.

Comment: If the line `if (opening.indexOf(c) != -1)` is eating you, then maybe you should **read the javadoc** of [`String.indexOf(char)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(int)) to learn what it does and what the return value `-1` means. I mean, the code in the loop is making *extensive* use of `indexOf()`, so if you don't grasp what it does, no wonder you're getting eaten.

Comment: I am using a small mobile phone. So its difficult to type the codes with all that indentations.

Comment: If your tool is deficient; dont go forward with the deficient tool and write up a deficient question. Consider using a better tool to create a better question. besides that Andreas nailed it: all those java standard libraries have excellent javadoc on them.

Comment: Oh sorry sir.  I thank Andreas and Yoyo for helping with my doubt.

Answer (score 0):

The indexOf("c") method  is used to return the index of first occurence of c in the given string. For example String s=" java";
int i= s.indexOf("a"); 
would set i = 1